# Number of solutions to $f_{2023}(x) = \frac{x}{23}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, contest-math

I have to find how many solutions there are for the following problem for my Introduction to Calculus course:
$$
\begin{split}
f_1(x) &= |x^2 - 1| \\
& \;\vdots\\
f_{2023}(x) &= \frac{x}{23}\\
& \;\vdots\\
f_{n+1}(x) &= |f_n(x) - 1| \\
\end{split}
$$
Before n = 529, the solutions are n+1 for odd n and n+2 for even n, when n goes beyond that number the solutions remain stable, so the solutions have to be 530. Someone mentioned that $f_{n+2}(x) = f_n(x)$, when $f_n(x) <= 1$
I will try to prove that $f_{529}(x) \leq 1$, by supposing the opposite so $f_{529}(x) > 1$.

Comment: What is being solved for?

Comment: I just have to find the number of solutions to the last line.

Comment: Hint: Iterate the function through the first few steps graphically rather than algebraically, and visualize what patterns appear. That is, graph $f_1$ by taking $x^2$ translating down by 1 and flipping everything negative to positive, then graph $f_2$ by taking $f_1$ translating down by 1 and flipping everything negative to positive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never thought about plotting the function. I got that the solutions are n+1, so in my case 2024. Now I have to prove it, I think proving it by induction would work.

Comment: As a warning, the pattern isn't $n+1$.  First, there's a difference between even and odd $n$.  Second (more importantly), something happens around $n=530$ that impacts the count for all higher $n$.

Comment: Thank you, I got too excited for some reason. I don't see the difference between even and odd $n$, except that the $0$ is a solution for even $n$. I am not sure why the pattern changes around $n = 530$, something about $23^2$ ?

Comment: I think I got it for $n >= 530$, the solutions are either 2 or 3, depending on if the function is odd or even. So for n = 2023 the solutions are 2.

Comment: Notice that if at some $n$ we have that for $ x \in (a,b) $ it is  $f_n(x) \le 1$ then $ f_{n+1}(x) \le 1 $ and $ f_{n+2}(x) = f_n(x)$. This implies that if at one point the solutions are for example 5 for one $ n $ and 6 for $n+1$ then they can never drop below these numbers (hint: but maybe at some point they stop increasing...)

Comment: I plotted the function for $f_{2023}(x) = \frac{x}{3}$ to observe the behavior when $n$ exceeds $x^2$.For $n < 9$, the solutions exhibit certain patterns: when $n$ is even, the solutions are $2n$, and when $n$ is odd, the solutions are $n+1$.However, when $n$ surpasses 9, the solutions remain stable at 10.I understand that $f_{n+2}(x) = f_n(x)$, when $f <= 1$ is. Thus, $f_{2023}(x)$ will have the same number of solutions as $f_{529}(x)$.I will attempt to prove this by contradiction: $f_{529}(x) > 1$.

Comment: For the last line, I meant I would try to prove that $f_{529}(x) \leq 1$ is true, by supposing the opposite.